# How to make an Email link in html

Tags: html, email

I want to make an Email link which direct to my Email.

**code:**

```
<a class="link" href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to=soesay2002@gmail.com' target='_blank' rel='noreferrer'">Email</a>
```

**Screenshot**
[image]

I want to direct to Gmail.com and ready to send Email with my Email address.

Comment: In Chrome, you can set the default mail client as Gmail: https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/set-gmail-as-browser-default-email-client-ht

Comment: I think it's best practice to simply provide the email as text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a 'share by email' link to website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045918/adding-a-share-by-email-link-to-website)

Comment: No, it is not same.

Comment: I try like that but it is do not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href='https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to=your.email@gmail.com' target='_blank' rel='noreferrer'>Email</a>
```

Comment: It is reach to gmail.com but (to input) is still blank. I want to add my email address to that place. is that possible. check my question. I will edit with a screenshot.

Comment: href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to=soesay2002@gmail.com' target='_blank' rel='noreferrer'">